# Scheduled Batch Apex Class Not Working

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I created a scheduled batch class that is supposed to update account's name field value. But it is not working.

**Batch Class**

```
global class UpdateAccountBatchCX implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    public static String con_exp = '0 0 0 20 3 ? 2017';
    public static String query;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        query = 'Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = \'testScheduledApexFromTestMethod\' ';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);    

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> accountList) {

        for(Account acc : accountList) {

            acc.Name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated';    

        }   

        update accountList;

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        System.schedule('Account Update Job', con_exp, new UpdateAccountBatchCX_Scheduler());   

    }

}
```

**Apex Scheduler**

```
global class UpdateAccountBatchCX_Scheduler implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        UpdateAccountBatchCX uab = new UpdateAccountBatchCX();
        database.executeBatch(uab);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any validation rules running on the account object?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Yes, there's a validation rule on account object. But I made it inactive.

Comment: Did you check  your apex jobs under monitoring and debug logs to see if you get any errors?

Comment: I don't see any apex jobs, and debug logs as well. The apex job list is completely empty.

Comment: Have you written a test class for your batch and scheduler classes? If so, please post them.

Comment: Try this and check your log afterwards:                                                                       UpdateAccountBatchCX updat = new UpdateAccountBatchCX();
Database.executebatch(updat);

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo After lots of refreshing, I tried what you suggested, and I got this status after code execution: `System.AsyncException: Based on configured schedule, the given trigger will never fire.`

Comment: Is your batch's execute even running? Why are you scheduling the batch again in your finish method?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo Thanks. It is working now. I just adjusted the time to a latest one, refreshed the developer console, and executed the code again. I checked the debug logs, and there I noticed that the job has been scheduled for execution. Maybe there's just an issue regarding the service availability?

Comment: That is good news :). Um, normally if you execute that line code from the developer console it should fire the batch, but is possible that has some delays.. anyway... good thing that it is working now.